# IOS Development vertical button

Tags: ios

in my project i want to do a vertical button and the text also vertical,,, anyone help ?!

something exactly like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to rotate the button

```
btn.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2);
```

And

```
btn.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instead rotate a button by using :

```
yrButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90.0*M_PI/180.0);
```

This will give you 90 Degree rorate.

Answer (score 0):

try like this i hope it'l helps you,

```
btn.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(270));
```

and define

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CGAffineTransform](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) for this purpose, it does the rotation according to your choice

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a transformation.

To rotate clock-wise:

```
button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90.0*M_PI/180.0);
```

and counter-clock-wise:

```
button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-90.0*M_PI/180.0);
```

The first number (90.0 or -90.0) specifies the angle (in degrees) by which you rotate the button.