# Show title vertically in a UIButton?

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton

I'm new to iPhone programming. And I'm stuck with this easy problem..

I have a `UIView` with a `UIButton` in it.
The dimension of `UIButton` is 40x200 close to the left margin.
I need to show the text vertically in the button..
Is there a way I can done this without using any images as the text is dynamic.?
I tried a vertical `UILabel` with a transperant `UIButton` over it. But I don't think it is the correct way..?
Any Help.
Can I do it with a `UIButton` alone?

Thanks..

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611118/ios-development-vertical-button

Comment: Please, clarify "vertical text" with an illustration in your post.

Comment: Like the image in first answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use character wrap

[image]

output based on your string

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `Character Wrap` mode wrapping behavior depends on button width, especially for non-monospace fonts. More stable solution is to insert newline `\n` symbol between text characters and set line break mode either to `Character Wrap` or `Word Wrap`.