# Creating Horizontall scroll with uibuttons in IOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, zooming, horizontalscrollview

How to create an horizontal scroll view with uibuttons on it. Three buttons must me shown on the screen and the middle one must zoom. I referred https://github.com/ninefifteen/SSRollingButtonScrollView and but the button text is not getting set vertically.

```html
e.g : referring above link I set word as "Alpha" but actually I wanted the button to show 
A
l
p
h
a
```

Also I want to set images on same buttons.
Guide me regarding the same.

Comment: Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678281/show-title-vertically-in-a-uibutton

Comment: How can I create an array of images stored in image_xcassets folder?

Comment: just use an nsmutabledictionary with keys for the images, then you win, or even better, I'd use an NSMutableOrderedSet, this is a sublcas of nsobject and works very well for stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the example :

```
NSArray *myButtonTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"l", @"p", @"h", @"a", nil];
```

Or you can split your string.

Or if you want one button to show vertical you can use it like this:

```
[button setTitle:@"A\nl\np\nh\na"... ];
```